# Concatenate variables in terraform V0.12

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to update my terraform files from V0.11 to V0.12 and I have some questions.

What's the best way to concatenate variables with strings?

In V0.11 I use this: `${var.name}-STRING-${var.name2}`, in V0.12 can I use this: `var.name"-STRING-"var.name2` or must I use another ways to concatenate variables and strings?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of available functions is available at https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html

For Python programmers I would suggest using `join` as another readable alternative:

```
join("-", [var.name, "STRING", var.name2])
```

Answer (score 4):

In v0.12 for interpolations like this:

```
"${var.example}"
```

You should use now:

```
var.example
```

In your example, In v0.12 you should keep using the previous syntax from v0.11:

```
"${var.name}-STRING-${var.name2}"
```

There is a great [section in Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html) about migrating to v0.12

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate, check few example below:

If you want to add '@' to string:

```
value = "${var.username}@${aws_instance.my-instance.public_dns}"
```

Output: abc@ec2-184-72-11-141.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

To create link:

```
value = "http://${aws_instance.my-instance.public_dns}:90"
```

Output: [http://ec2-184-72-11-141.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:90](http://---)

Answer (score 3):

Former C Programmers might like this function better:

```
format("%s-STRING-%s", var.name, var.name2)
```

For me, it's less clunky than the old $-Syntax